# Manually add collocations to gensim phraser

Tags: gensim, topic-modeling

I am doing topic modelling on linguistics papers and I am using the Gensim Phrases to identify frequent collocations. I want to be able to mark terms as 'do-support' and 'it-clefts' as one single word, since they are specific linguistic terminology. However, if I make the Gensim model after taking out stopwords, these collocations will not be found (since they contain stopwords), if I make the model after taking out stopwords (or stopwords not including 'it' or 'do'), it identifies a whole lot of irrelevant collocations. Is there a way to manually add phrases that should be recognised as collocations by the Gensim Phrases? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `Phrases` class doesn't have the ability to add desired bigrams. Its technique generally does *not* expect 'stop words' to have been removed before processing.

You could potentially tune `Phrases` behavior by trying different 'threshold' and 'min_count' values.

If you find some settings *are* connecting desired-phrases, but then also some unwanted phrases that still fit the same statistical thresholds, maybe that's not a great harm, despite the non-intuitiveness of some of the phrases. All these statistical techniques are imprecise, and often best judged by their end results on quantitative goals – rather than any arbitrary oddities/corner-cases found from an ad-hoc review.

If you did want to dig into the code to add the ability to force certain bigrams, it might be easier via the `Phraser` utility class, also in gensim's `phrases.py` module. At the cost of some extra up-front calculation, it reduces the `Phrases` data to a smaller structure, with just the bigrams that would later pass the combination-threshold. As such, it saves a bit of memory, and performs later corpus-transformations a little faster, but if you only keep the `Phraser`, you lose the ability to try other thresholds/min_counts below what was used in its creation. But you could potentially force extra hand-chosen bigrams into its structures, after creation, more easily than tampering with the full `Phrases` model.

**Update (April 2021):** Starting in Gensim-4.0, the `Phraser` class has been renamed `FrozenPhrases`, for better distinction from the training `Phrases` class. Additionally, a [suggestion in a project issue](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1465#issuecomment-706620266) provides a probably-effective way to 'force' certain bigram-phrases to always be promoted. Specifically:

```py
phrases = Phrases(…)  # do customary training/etc
frozen_phrases = phrases.freeze()  # freeze bigrams' scores for compactness/efficiency
frozen_phrases.phrasegrams['my_phrase'] = float('inf')  # set the desired phrase to infinite score
```

Comment: Hi @gojomo. Can you please let me know if you know how to fix this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735393/gensim-phrases-usage-to-filter-n-grams