# Gensim Phrases usage to filter n-grams

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, gensim

I am using Gensim Phrases to identify important n-grams in my text as follows.

```
bigram = Phrases(documents, min_count=5)
trigram = Phrases(bigram[documents], min_count=5)

for sent in documents:
    bigrams_ = bigram[sent]
    trigrams_ = trigram[bigram[sent]]
```

However, this detects uninteresting n-grams such as `special issue`, `important matter`, `high risk` etc. I am particularly, interested in detecting concepts in the text such as `machine learning`, `human computer interaction` etc.

Is there a way to stop phrases detecting uninteresting  n-grams as I have mentioned above in my example?

Comment: Define "uninteresting" or "interesting".

Comment: @CharlesPehlivanian I have given examples

Answer (score 3):

`Phrases` has a configurable `threshold` parameter which adjusts the statistical cutoff for promoting word-pairs into phrases. (Larger thresholds mean fewer pairs become phrases.)

You can adjust that to try to make a greater proportion of its promoted phrases match your own ad hoc intuition about "interesting" phrases – but this class is still using a fairly crude method, without any awareness of grammar or domain knowledge beyond what's in the corpus. So any value that gets all/most of the phrases you want will likely include many uninteresting ones, or vice-versa.

If you have a priori knowledge that certain word-groups are of importance, you could preprocess the corpus yourself to combine those into single tokens, before (or instead of) the collocation-statistics-based `Phrases` process.

Comment: Thanks a lot gojomo :) I will try to implement the latter idea you proposed :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you could try tf_idf on your corpus compared to the tf_idf of a larger, say, standard corpus (wikipedia or something).

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import 

TfidfVectorizertfidf_vectorizer = 
    TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=500,min_df=0.2,
                    stop_words='english', use_idf=True, ngram_range=(1,2))
X = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(docs)  # transform the documents to their tf_idf vectors
```

Look only at ngrams that have a very different value, this of course will only work if you have a large enough number of documents.

Comment: I have a similar kind of a question and I would like to try your answer. But I am not clear why you say "ngrams that have a very different value" are the most important ngrams. Could you please elaborate it further. Thank you :)

Comment: This was a while ago and I slightly forgot what I meant but I guess what I meant could have been something like 1. use TFIDF on a large corpus that is similar to your domain to get a basic language model like ngram and then 2. only use those ngrams when searching your corpus.