# Gensim phrases don`t find some bigrams

Tags: python, gensim, phrase

I want to get bigrams for symbols (letters of words). For example, for words "done" and "dog" I want to be able to find bigram "do".

I tried to do it using gensim.Phrases, but it doesn`t work for me.

Here is my code:

```
from gensim.models import Phrases

documents = ["God", "Good","happy","hangry","pypi"]
documents_proc = [list(doc) for doc in documents]

bigram = Phrases(documents_proc, min_count=1)
trigram = Phrases(bigram[documents_proc], min_count=1)

for sent in documents_proc:
    print(sent, bigram[sent])
    bigrams_ = [b for b in bigram[sent] if b.count('_') == 1]
    trigrams_ = [t for t in trigram[bigram[sent]] if t.count('_') == 2]
    print(bigrams_)
    print(trigrams_)
    print()
```

I expected the output of
`['Go', 'od', 'ha', 'py']`, but there are nothing in the output. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Gensim's `Phrases` class uses a simple statistical analysis based on relative counts & some tunable thresholds to decide some token-pairs (usually word pairs rather than character pairs) should be promoted to a single connected bigram. Potential pairings are given a 'score', and those that score over a configurable 'threshold' are combined.

Even when used in its normal domain, words, its results often won't seem impressive to human evaluation – missing many combinations we'd consider logical, making other combinations we'd group differently. But, with a lot of training data, and some tuning of its parameters, even its imperfect combinations may help downstream models perform better.

For your tiny toy corpus, the character bigrams you'd like to see aren't qualifying, based on the class defaults.

You can view the default `original_scorer()` code for scoring potential pairings at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/460dc1cb9921817f71b40b412e11a6d413926472/gensim/models/phrases.py#L663

You can run this code on your model for one of your expected pairings, to see its score:

```
>>> from gensim.models.phrases import original_scorer
>>> original_scorer(bigram.vocab[b'G'], bigram.vocab[b'o'], 
                    bigram.vocab[b'G_o'], len(bigram.vocab), 
                    bigram.min_count, bigram.corpus_word_count)
4.666666666666666
```

Compared to the default `bigram.threshold` of `10.0`, this `'G_o'` bigram won't make the cut.

You can tinker with the `threshold` (or other parameters of `Phrases`), to get different results, but what values/tradeoffs are best will depend on your ultimate goals. For example:

```
>>> bigram.threshold = 4.0
>>> list(bigram.export_phrases(documents_proc, out_delimiter=b''))
[(b'Go', 4.666666666666666),
 (b'Go', 4.666666666666666),
 (b'od', 4.666666666666666),
 (b'ha', 7.0),
 (b'ha', 7.0)]
>>> list(bigram[documents_proc])
[['G_o', 'd'],
 ['G_o', 'o_d'],
 ['h_a', 'p', 'p', 'y'],
 ['h_a', 'n', 'g', 'r', 'y'],
 ['p', 'y', 'p', 'i']]
```

So, with `bigram.threshold=4.0`, your desired `'p_y'` is still not there - as it'd need an even lower `threshold` given the counts of `'p'` and `'y'`.

Comment: It explains everything. I've just tried different values of threshold and it began work in my real case. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any way to train a Phrase extractor, and then force it to add some manually selected bigrams in it?

Comment: For a way that might work to force-add desired phrases, see discussion & latest update at this other relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45806582/130288